# Wpf и горячие клавишы

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, hotkeys

### Проблема 1

Да, я знаю как использовать хоткеи (XAML):

```
...    
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="A" Modifiers="Alt" Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Close}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
...
```

Клавиши просто для примера. Дело в том, что, когда я нажимаю, например, `Alt+B`, то комп издает звук ошибки, а когда нажимаю `Alt+A`, то этого звука нет. Это значит, что "реакция" на нажатие есть, а закрытие окна не выполняется. Я пробовал использовать `Gesture` и менял значение атрибута `Command`:

```
...    
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Alt+A" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
...
```

Но ничего не помогает.

### Проблема 2

В добавок есть ещё 1 проблема с модификаторами клавиш (`Ctrl`, `Shift`, `Alt`, `Windows` или `None`). если я укажу любой модификатор (в разметке), наведу курсор на `KeyBinding` и посмотрю на панель "Свойства", то модификатор там отобразится. Но это не работает с `Ctrl`. Если я возьму и вместо `Alt+A` (из второй разметки) поставлю `Ctrl+A`, то в свойстве `Modifiers` (из панели "Свойства") ничего не отобразится. Тут не знаю, что и сказать.

---

Хотелось бы решить обе проблемы. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А `ApplicationCommands.Close` в том контексте? Вероятнее всего нет, поставьте в него точку остановки.

Comment: По 1 читайте отсюда и дальше: https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level9/9_2.php